# Locally defined symbol from STL streams?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, fstream

I'm getting this odd link error in VS2013:

```
1>tracdata.obj : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol ?is_open@?$basic_fstream@DU?
$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QBE_NXZ (public: bool __thiscall
std::basic_fstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::is_open(void)const ) imported
```

I'm calling stream.is_open(), but as far as I know I'm not defining it myself.

I'm using boost 1.56.0 along with the standard MS built-in STL libs.  I'm using the STL stream class (not the boost one).

```
#pragma once

#include <sys/stdinc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>


class SYSCMMN_EXPORT File
{
    File( const File& file );
    void operator=( const File& );
public:
    File();
    File( const char* filename, std::ios_base::open_mode mode = std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out );
    virtual ~File();

    const char*      Access() const;
    const char*      GetName() const
    {
        return filename.c_str();
    }
    bool             isValid()   const
    {
        return fs.is_open();
    }
    // ... (snipped for brevity)
protected:
    std::string      filename;
    std::fstream     fs;
    std::ios_base::open_mode mode;
};
```

Comment: I tried adding "inline" to the isValid() method.  Same result.

Comment: Try moving the protected section above the public section.  If that successfully resolves the local symbol error message, then there is a compiler problem.  Is SYSCMMN_EXPORT a macro?  If so, what does it expand to?

Comment: Figured it out!  So the class is part of a DLL project that links to another static lib project.  In each one they were using different macros to define the __declspec(dllimport/dllexport) on each class.  The problem is that I needed to define the same macro in the DLL that was defined in the static lib.  Stupid oversight.  But this is legacy code that I'm trying to understand.  CPlusPlus, your instincts were correct.  The problem was related to the SYSCMMN_EXPORT macro.  Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome.  After searching my development system for the macro and not finding it defined anywhere, I am glad my question helped resolve the problem.